# How to build OpenJ9 for use with Kotlin without (open)JDK

Tags: kotlin, jvm, open-source, building, openj9

I need to develop my apps in Kotlin and choose to use openj9 as my virtual machine for windows/linux.
However, besides AUR builds, I only see auto-adopt-openjdk windows builds and openjdk build instructions.
I'm not planning to use that because I choose a non-copyleft open-source development environment besides OS.

Is there a way to get a build done without OpenJdk or should I stick to using the Arch Linux openj9 AUR build for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an agreement, there's no use.
IKVM .Net might be better, but I have no clue about the license.